# How to Get SubView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which has added viewController.view .How to get subview in scroll view.

Everyone Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to get the subview from? An idea of how you have architected this setup will be required to make any kind of comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to add your view in scroll view then:

```
[yourScrollView addSubview:yourSubView];
```

and if you want to get that view then you can :

```
if ([yourScrollView subviews])
    {
        for (UIView *subview in [yourScrollView subviews]) 
        {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:yourClassName])
            {
                //Code 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Maulik i m not get UIViewcontroller

Comment: are you getting your uiview ? (which is added in your uiviewcontroller )

Answer (score 1):

Since `UIScrollView` inherits from `UIView`, you can use [`-addSubview:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a).

Answer (score 1):

```
[yourscrollview subviews]; // This gives you all subviews added
```

If you want to add subviews then you can use the -addSubview method.

You can get all this info from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).